# GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync token expiring in 30 minutes on live server only

Tags: c#, asp.net

on my asp.net website i have used the code from this microsoft link ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-registerconfirmation ) to generate verification code to be send for user confirmation in email. this code was expiring in 30 minutes so i applied the changes given here ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#resend-email-confirmation  in **change all data protection token lifespan** section) to add tokenlifespan to 24 hours in my startup.cs file and its working correctly on my local. however when i moved my website.dll and view.dll files to live and suspended then activated the server again (bcoz i think that changes in startup files applies after restart) its still expiring in 30 minutes on live server.

can anyone help me why is this issue appearing on live ?

my code for generating the token in register.cshtml.cs file:

```
if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount){
    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
        pageHandler: null,
        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code },
        protocol: Request.Scheme);

    var data = new TransactionEmailTemplate()
    {
        Subject = "Email Verification | site title",
        Header = "Email Verification",
        Text = $"Please verify your email address by clicking on the button below.",
        C2AButton = "Verify",
        C2ALink = $"{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}"
    };

    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(data, Models.Enums.EmailType.WithC2A, Input.Email);
    return RedirectToPage("./.....", new { Email = Input.Email });
}
```

my startup.cs file ConfigureServices function code for increasing token life span:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            o => o.EnableRetryOnFailure(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null)));

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
            o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
    {
        o.LoginPath = "/identity/account/login";
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    services.AddScoped<Services.Email.IEmailSender, Services.Email.EmailSender>();
    services.Configure<Services.Email.EmailSenderOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(Services.Email.EmailSenderOptions.EmailSender));

    services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
    services.ConfigureNonBreakingSameSiteCookies();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
            Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

            options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
        })
        .AddLinkedIn(options =>
        {
            IConfigurationSection linkedinAuthNSection =
            Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Linkedin");

            options.ClientId = linkedinAuthNSection["ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = linkedinAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
        });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of linking to code snippets on other websites, you should include your own code within the question. Links can grow stale and then no one will be able to reproduce your issue later on.

Comment: thanks. now i have added my code also